ECS task fails n times before working correctly
I'm running nexus on ECS using ec2 instance as a capacity provider.The nexus service is working  fine but after a long period (11 minutes 8 for deployment and 3 fot ALB target health check).What I noticed that there is some warnings fails (6 fails) before deployment turns to completed.Here  is a  picture that clarifies the fail status.

What I'm doubting is a correct health check grace period config  (I set it  to 180s)  but  I don't know if it is the correct config.I changed this  value so many times but it doesn't seem to make a difference.I noticed also that when I run more  then a service on the same cluster but the two services are separated in two different  capacity providers (2 VM ),it takes more time to complete deployment.I don't know if this makes sense or not but may be it will be a useful information.I hope that so has encountered this issue before and  the  provided info will be enough to understand the problem.
